# Adding a hard and soft upper bound constraint of number of locations to visit (VRP)

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I went through the [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp) example and was able to replicate it. On the example, there is a constraint added for vehicle maximum distance as shown below:

```python
dimension_name = 'Distance'
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,  # no slack
    3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    dimension_name)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

Similar to the [CVRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp), how do I modify the constraint for the number of locations that each vehicle can visit (either global or by each vehicle) rather than the demand?

Answer (score 6):

Crossposted from: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786554/adding-a-hard-and-soft-upper-bound-constraint-of-number-of-locations-to-visit-v)

The idea is to create another dimension ('visit') that is incremented by 1 on each visit.
Then use `SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound` on the cumul variable of that dimension at the end of each route.